# Nested interceptors in Nest.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

How to implement a nested interceptor in Nest.js?

I have two interceptors: `UsersInterceptor` and `PostsInterceptor`

**UsersInterceptor:**

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersInterceptor<T> implements NestInterceptor<T, Response<T>> {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<Response<T>> {
    return next.handle().pipe(map(data => ({
      id: data._id,
      email: data.email,
      createdAt: data.createdAt
    })));
  }
}
```

**PostsInterceptor:**

```
@Injectable()
export class PostsInterceptor<T> implements NestInterceptor<T, Response<T>> {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<Response<T>> {
    return next.handle().pipe(map(data => ({
      id: data._id,
      title: data.title,
      content: data.content,
      user: {}, // I want the UsersInterceptor result here. I have the user's data in data.user
      createdAt: data.createdAt
    })));
  }
}
```

Now, I want to put the `UserInterceptor`'s result into the `user` object in the `PostsInterceptor` when I use it.

Answer (score 1):

[As described in the request lifecycle docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/request-lifecycle#interceptors), interceptors work on the incoming request in the order they are bound, and on the outgoing response in the inverse order they are bound. This means that if you bind your interceptors like `@UseInterceptors(PostInterceptor, UserInterceptor)` then you should be able to see `UserInterceptor`'s return in the `PostInterceptor`

Comment: And how can I tell the `PostsInterceptor` to load the `user` object from the `UsersInterceptor` ?

Comment: It should be in the `data` that is returned. So long as `UserInterceptor` adds it to the returned data, it'll be there